# How to make active page have a border on the right side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, border

I have a navigation bar that has a hover effect for the buttons. I am trying to make it so whenever a page is active that button has a border on the right to show that it's the page that is currently open. I have everything setup but I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```js
function homeTransition()
{   
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage');

    if(document.getElementById("aboutContent").className.indexOf("slideInLeft") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("projectsContent").className.indexOf("slideInUp") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("contactContent").className.indexOf("slideInUp") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    }
    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceInDown";
}

function aboutTransition()
{   
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
    
    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("aboutContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = "activePage animated slideInLeft";

    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

function projectsTransition()
{   
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage');

    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = "activePage animated slideInUp";

    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

function contactTransition()
{
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage');

    document.getElementById("homeContent").className = " animated bounceOutUp";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("contactContent").className = "activePage animated slideInUp";

    document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutRight";
    document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutUp";
}

//Menu
$(function() {
    function expand() {
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
        $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
    };

    $('.noselect').click(function() {
        $('.noselect').removeClass('activePage');
        $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
    });

    $(".button").on('click', expand);
});
```

```css
 body {
     font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
     color: #ccc;
     z-index: -100;
     background-color: black;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
}
 .menu{
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     width: 250px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     transition: all 250ms;
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
     text-align:center;
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
 .active {
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
     transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
     -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
     transition: 0.4s;
     color: #e5e5e5;
}
 ul{
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: .875em;
}
 li{
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: "Raleway";
     width: 250px;
     padding: 16% 2%;
     color: #a7a7a7;
     font-size: 1.8em;
     font-weight: 300;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
 li:hover {
     color: white;
     background-color: #38d8b4;
     -o-transition: .6s;
     -ms-transition: .6s;
     -moz-transition: .6s;
     -webkit-transition: .6s;
     transition: .6s;
}
 .activePage li {
     transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
     color: white;
     border-right: 8px solid #38d8b4;
}
 .activePage li:hover {
   border-right: 8px solid #38d8a1;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);;
 }
 .liSeperator {
     width: 100%;
     padding: .5%;
     color: (0, 0, 0, .4);
}
 .content {
     position: relative;
     width: 240px;
}
 .button {
     width:22px;
     height:40px;
     margin:80px 97px;
     padding: 10px;
     cursor:pointer;
     transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
 .button:hover{
     transform: scale(1.2);
}
 .line {
     width: 40px;
     height: 2px;
     background-color:#fff;
     transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}
 .line.first{
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}
 .line.second{
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}
 .button.on .line.top{
     width: 40px;
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}
 .button.on .line.bottom{
     width: 40px;
     transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
                                    <div class="menu">
                                        <h1 class="noselect">MENU</h1>
                                        <ul>
                                                <li id="home" class="noselect" onclick="homeTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i> home
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="about" class="noselect" onclick="aboutTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> about
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="projects" class="noselect" onclick="projectsTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-code"></i> projects
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="liSeperator"></div>
                                                <li id="contact" class="noselect" onclick="contactTransition()">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> contact
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="content animated fadeInDown">
                                        <div class="button">
                                            <div class="line first top"></div>
                                            <div class="line second bottom"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Look in your browser console. You're trying to alter the `className` on id's like `#homeContent`, `#aboutContent`, etc and those elements don't exist.

Comment: I have those in my html file, I just didnt include them because this post is mainly about the menu. Those ID's are my pages that slide in when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Then you should reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If you removed irrelevant HTML, why wouldn't you also remove the irrelevant JS? How are we supposed to know what errors are on purpose because you excluded code and what errors are part of your OP?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting `.activePage li:hover`  just do `.activePage`

```
.activePage {
   border-right: 8px solid #38d8a1;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);;
 }
 .activePage:hover {
   border-right: 8px solid red;
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just add the border when it is hovered? I want it to have the border whenever the buttons page is opened.

Comment: Ok, this works great, except for some reason this also adds a border to the right of the pages that slide in when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: I can't see any such behaviour in codepen.Is it happening in codepen, or in your local code. With right of page you mean right side in browser?

Comment: Ok I will figure that out, but last problem is that when I hover over the button that is active the li hover covers it up. How can I make it so that the hover effect doesnt work on the active button?

Comment: on hover it must be different color to differentiate.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdKYvo

Comment: @OpticLukie you should accept answer if it solves your problem.